# I can't fill manually a "text item" in Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm using Oracle Forms 6i and I don't know why I can't fill an input (text item) of a Data Block.
The Data Block is not attached to a table, and its data type is Date.
I don't know which is the property that doesn't allow you to change the value of the text item.

Properties of text item:

http://postimg.org/gallery/3au3yay8/c6e0d918/

http://postimg.org/gallery/7qsjor74/7dd56436/

Thanks!

Comment: The properties looks alright. Must be something else causing the problem. Do you get an error or in which way you are able enter a value to the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, searching for the words "update_allowed", I found that at some point the update_allowed was set to false and I fixed it, with the following statement:

SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('block.element_name' update_allowed, property_true);

Thanks!